# Using WP_Query to grab custom meta values, foreach to json object

Tags: jquery, metabox, ajax, json

So I have 4 custom meta boxes for each post on a wordpress site relating to the product this client sells.

I have 3 dropdown boxes, one for category, and two for two of the custom meta boxes. The meta boxes I'm dealing with are `adhesion_box` and `substrate_box`.

My AJAX script works fine when I query the post titles, but when I try to grab the meta values, it won't work. I'm attempting to use `WP_Query` for this instead of `$wpdb`. Here is the php bit that isn't working:

```
$cat   = $post['cat'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '$cat' ) );

if($query->have_posts()){
    $posts = $query->get_posts();
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $return[$post->id] = $post->meta_value;
    }
}
```

Right now the JSON object it returns is:

```
OBJECT: {"":""}
```

So I'm a little lost. Here is the long $wpdb query that my friend wrote that grabs the post titles by category - it works just fine, but I need the `adhesion_box` meta value, not the post title.

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT p.`id`,p.`post_title`
    FROM $wpdb->posts `p`
    JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships `tr` ON (`p`.`ID` = `tr`.`object_id`)
    JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy `tt` ON (`tr`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `tt`.`term_taxonomy_id`)
    JOIN $wpdb->terms `t` ON (`tt`.`term_id` = `t`.`term_id`)
    WHERE `p`.`post_type`='post'
    AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish'
    AND `tt`.`taxonomy` = 'category'
    AND `t`.`term_id` = '$cat'");
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to grab that value, and do it in the simplest way.

Any help appreciated.

[Here is the demo, so you can see it](http://carotape.bigwolfdesigns.com/product-selector/).

Comment: There the property `meta_value` isn't part of the `$post` object, so naturally you won't get anything back by trying to access it. There are extra [functions for accessing post meta data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Function_Reference).

Comment: So I should change that line to:

`$return[$post->id] = get_post_meta($post->id, 'adhesion_box', true);`

Comment: Should work, if thats actually the name of the custom field.

Comment: returns `OBJECT: {"":false}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about this is with `$wpdb`. The query to draw out meta_value by category is:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT p.`ID`, pm.`meta_value` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} `p` ON `p`.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} `tr` ON `p`.`ID` = `tr`.`object_id`
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} `tt` ON `tr`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `tt`.`term_taxonomy_id`
    WHERE `pm`.`meta_key` = 'adhesion_box'
    AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish'
    AND `p`.`post_type` = 'post'
    AND `tt`.`taxonomy` = 'category'
    AND `tt`.`term_id` = $cat
");
```